# Object related JavaScript confusion

Tags: javascript, oop, dom-events

I am getting confused with the internal working of DOM. 
Eg: Does `document.form.write()` means that there are 2 objects  "document" and "form" of nested classes.
OOPS representation:

```
class A{

    class B{

         write();

    }form;

}document;



main()
{
document.form.write("Hello World");
}
```

I want to know that what does FORM refer to. Is it a Method or Object in DOM?

Comment: Sort of. But then again not exactly. Or necessarily (I believe). Could you specify your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each level is an object which is what js does instead of classes. Imagine it like this:

```
var tellMeStuff = function(a) { print(a); };
var formOnThePage = {
    method: 'post',
    action: 'form.php',
    write: tellMeStuff
};
var document = { 
    property = 'the page',
    form: formOnThePage        
};
```